# Brazil Visit Visa can take UK Transit Visa

Tags: pakistan

My question is this that I have Brazil Visit visa, while traveling to Brazil my flight is connected from London to Brazil, in that case can I apply transit visa for UK to go outside? I have Pakistan passport.

Regards.!

Comment: You can apply for a transit visa. You are not guaranteed to receive it.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply for a [Visitor In Transit Visa](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa) which will allow you to pass through UK Border Control and remain landside for up to 48 hours.

Note that London's airports are not close to the centre of London. If your layover is less than about 8 hours there won't be anything 'outside' that you'll have time to get to, return, and pass through security again.

Comment: That's a little disingenuous.  I don't know what your criteria are for "close", but LHR is only 22 minutes from Central London by train, and LCY 21min.  London's other airports are slightly further (Gatwick 32min, Stansted 46min) but all the destination termini are in Central London (ie, Underground Zone 1).  I admit that Luton is in the wilderness, but it's unlikely that the OP's flights will be going in and out of that hole.

Comment: @madhatter 22 minutes from LHR will take you to Paddington, as much a 'hole' as Luton. Compare that with around 15 minute from SYD - right outside the opera house. My point is that there's nothing 'outside' the airport  (unless one wants to visit Harmondsworth before it's demolished) so the OP needs to allow plenty of time.

Comment: If you're going to define the centre of a city as "*right outside the opera house*", then I'll concede the point (LHR to the Royal Opera House is about 58min).  I'm just not sure most people define a city centre that way.  I was last in Paddington on Saturday, and I can't say I found it a hole; certainly much more congenial than Luton Airport, and quite definitely central London.  My point is that, depending on where the OP arrives, what (s)he wants to see in London, and how long (s)he has, a trip into town may well be possible; to say one can see nothing in an 8-hour layover is unhelpful.